# Trying to add a center title to my page

Tags: css, html

I'm looking to add a center text title in the middle of my page and it won't show up. Code seems correct, don't see a bug.

```
<div id="welcome_text_div">
  <p id="welcome_text"> Welcome </p>
</div>


#welcome_text_div {
position: absolute;
background-color:red;
width:800px;
height:300px;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -150%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -400px;

}

#welcome_text {
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 55px;
text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers, worked perfect!

Comment: If something worked for you, please select an answer so that they may receive credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use text-align: center and it should center automatically. BTW I see you are using ids often which is very bad practice. IDs should be used for javasscript selectors while class for css.

```css
.center-text {
  text-align:center;
}

.title-text {
  // Do css formating here  
}
```

```html
 <div class="center-text title-text">
  <p class="page-title"> Welcome </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
  #welcome_text_div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color:red;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
    
    #welcome_text {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 800px;
    line-height: 300px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="welcome_text_div">
      <p id="welcome_text"> Welcome </p>
    </div>
```

```
<div id="welcome_text_div">
   <p id="welcome_text"> Welcome </p>
</div>


#welcome_text_div {
position: absolute;
background-color:red;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

#welcome_text {
color: white;
font-family: sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 55px;
text-align: center;
width: 800px;
line-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with flexbox.

All you need to do to the container is define its width and height (and give it a bg color):

```
#welcome_text_div {
    background-color:red;
    width:800px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Then add these three lines to set the flexbox display context, and center it vertically and horizontally:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

Then remove all the extra formatting from your inner div.

```
#welcome_text_div {
    background-color:red;
    width:800px;
    height:300px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

#welcome_text {
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 55px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k5zve6bf/